# Adding bindings to multiple SSL certificates for the same site IIS

Tags: iis, ssl, iis-8.5

Given the following scenario; i have 2 domains - mysite.com and deploymysite.com, mysite.com is pointed at our live server farm which is created from an image of our deploy machine.

I want to point the domain deploymysite.com at this deploy machine. I have an SSL certificate for *.mysite.com which of course does not work for deploymysite.com.

If I purchase an additional SSL certificate for this domain, is it possible in IIS (8.5) to add a separate SSL certificate for the 'same site' but have it bound to a different domain?

I'm looking at the site bindings dialog, and specifically the IP address field,  wondering if it is possible to configure this with 2 SSL certs for 2 different domains for the same site?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need it to be one site you must have one certificate with entries for both domains.

You can host multiple sites with duplicate content on a single IP by using Server Name Indication (SNI) but then they won't share state.

Alternatively you can host a redirect on the 2nd site.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will investigate SNI as you have suggested, hopefully that will be enough for what I need. Cheers.

Comment: The thing you want to compare it to is called a SAN certificate